# would this be possible

Tags: php, cron, server-side

is there anyway to run an cron job + use cURL to call a video ?

in other words is it possible to have server side scripts parse the cURL url video and increase the view count on it.

Is there some sort of server side "browser" or something of that nature?

Comment: and why would you want to do that

Comment: @AD7six i think it's none of your business. He can do what he wants ?

Comment: well the example i give is to increase a vids view count, but then if this was possible, that a server-side script can behave more like a browser then alot of doors would be open

Comment: @NeeL you would willingly aide someone to do something unethical?

Comment: @AD7six actually he just want to increase a video count. It's not like really bad. And he will get banip from youtube if it's for youtube so i think it's ok to answer his question if this is possible or not.

Comment: Most video services will quickly detect this sort of thing and will probably end up banning your server IP if it persists.

Comment: @NeeL of course it's possible. Anything that you can do with a browser can be done with a script. But the question is a pretty clear indicator of wanting to do something that you should't be trying to do. If nothing else the question shows no effort to find a solution.

Comment: i understand you are having a moral debate here, but this is unfair to say that i did not have any effort to find a solution;

Comment: @FrankLy apart from context, your question is how to use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) with cron - both of which have huge amounts of [google-fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=cron) and [SO-fu](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl). I stand by my statements, anyway - good luck ;).

Comment: i understand how to use curl with cron, i used it for scrapping before, the reason i believe that it was not working and hence my question was that i was calling the hosted page instead of the swf url directly like @David-SkyMesh has suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [libcurl](http://au.php.net/curl) PHP bindings, from a CRON job which executes your script with php5-cli.

You'd need to GET the URL of the video file directly, not the hosted page. That might force you to supply the 'referer' (sic) HTTP header.

Also, the site you're "inflating" the view count on might not appreciate it, or might simply not count your hits after a while.

Comment: Most sites with a view counter rely on cookies to some extent. Either only counting identified users or only counting requests from "users" who have previously loaded the page the html is on (which loads some js, which sets a cookie). In other words, it's not likely to be that simple.

Comment: Indeed, a site might make you jump through a great many hoops. It's not a good idea in general, but question _was_ asked.